# Máximo de caracteres en tres frases

Tags: javascript

Quiero el máximo número de caracteres en tres frases.

Código:

```
var texto2 = prompt("ingrese primer frase2");
document.write (texto2.length,'<br>');

var texto3 = prompt("ingrese segunda frase");
document.write (texto3.length,'<br>');

var texto4 = prompt("ingrese tercera frase");
document.write (texto4.length,'<br>');

alert("la funcion Math.max() su resultado es "+ Math.max(texto2,texto3,texto4));
```

Comment: Parece que lo que te falta es simplemente añadir .length cuando estás pasando las variables en `Math.max` asi: `Math.max(texto2.length, texto3.length, texto4.length)`

Comment: for(var i = 0; i < 1 ; i++)
var texto = prompt("ingrese texto1");
var texto = prompt("ingrese texto2");
var texto = prompt("ingrese texto3");
document.write (texto.length,'<br>');
alert("la funcion Math.max() su resultado es "+ Math.max(texto1,texto2,texto3));

Answer (score -1):

for(var i = 0; i < 1 ; i++)
var texto = prompt("ingrese texto1");

var texto = prompt("ingrese texto2");

var texto = prompt("ingrese texto3");

document.write (texto.length,'
');

alert("la funcion Math.max() su resultado es "+ Math.max(texto1,texto2,texto3));

//al final me funciono asi,, pero ahora tengo otro eje donde tengo que ingresar frases y

el programa termina con una palabra y me tiene que contar cuantas frases ingrese.... les

muestro lo que puse pero no me funciona.... alguien que me ayude...
var c = 0;

var clave = " ";

while(clave!= "suficiente"){

var texto = prompt("ingrese texto");

c++

}

alert("la funcion Math.max() su resultado es "+ Math.max(texto));